# Insert url in css class when data has been received from api in Angular2

Tags: html, css, angular

I am working on an Angular 2 project where I'm getting data from the IMDb API. In this case I need to show the poster/image of the movie every time I receive data (if a user have searched for a movie).

**HTML**

```
<div class="column small-12 medium-8 movie-information gutter-large-up end">
    <div class="gutter-xxsmall-up">
        {{MovieFromImdb.Title}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{MovieFromImdb.Year}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{MovieFromImdb.Rating}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{MovieFromImdb.Genre}}
    </div>
    <div class="movie-picture">
          // Image here  
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.movie-picture {
    height: 20rem;
    width: 15rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5rem;
    background: url('');
    background-size: cover;
    left: 0.5rem;
    border: 1px solid #364d63;
}
```

So every time my object `MovieFromImdb` is not `null` (has some data), I want to show the information, but also show the image.

How can I put it inside the `background: url('');` when I receive it, using Angular 2?

Answer (score 2):

Using [ngStyle](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/common/index/NgStyle-directive.html), you could do this:

```
<div class="movie-picture" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + selectedMovie.url + ')'}">
    //Image here
</div>
```

In this situation `selectedMovie.url` will be the url set on your controller's scope. So when the data gets returned from the imdb api, it will set the background image.

Comment: Using "background-image" it would retain the configuration for "background-size:cover" present in the stylesheet.